# Using a godaddy domain with a private VPS

Tags: dns, vps

I have a website hosted running on a `VPS`. I can access the site via the browser with an IP address. I want to be able to access it using the domain name i have with `GoDaddy`.

So far I have added a host name in `GoDaddy`.`NS1.MYDOMAIN.COM = IP address`. I did this yesterday and when I look up the name-servers for my domain on who is the new host-name I made in `GoDaddy` is showing up as the first name-server for the domain but its pointing to the ip of the old host.

The `VPS` is hosted with `OVH`. A tutorial on the site says to enter the first name-server based on my account number E.G. `nsXXXX.ovh.fr`. I tried this but `GoDaddy` returns an error saying "You must enter a registered name-server".

`GoDaddy` wont let me edit anything in the `DNS` zone file tab because it says the name-servers aren't pointing at it.

Answer (score 10):

Sounds like you changed the nameserver address of your domain instead of adding a host record which it sounds like was your intention.

You should let GoDaddy run your name servers (unless you plan on having your DNS hosted elsewhere). Then you will be able to edit the zone file and add an A record for your domain.

**Step 1:**

Under Settings tab, Nameservers click manage and make sure Standard is selected.

**Step 2:**

Under DNS Zone File (assuming you can now edit this) click Add Record.
Record type: A (Host)
Host: yourdomain.com
Points to: your IP address
TTL: Leave default (1 hour)

Make sure you save your changes.

Might take a few hours to propagate so don't panic if it doesn't work immediately.

Answer (score 0):

'Setting up DNS with Your Parallels Plesk Panel 11 Server and Domain with Us' may be helpful to you. Here's a link: Setting up DNS with Your Parallels Plesk Panel 11 Server and Domain with Us.

Link to file 
http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/8463?locale=en&ci=46061